# Can Someone Combine these 3 scripts

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Can't get this to work. The first part is a toggle function (mouse button 8) which functions with the use of mouse button 1 being pressed and released. The second part (mouse button 7) is just a "click to use" functionality.

first part

```
local enabled = false

function IsLeftNotPressed()
    return not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_ACTIVATED")
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        return
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_DEACTIVATED")
        ReleaseMouseButton(1) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
        return
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
        enabled = not enabled
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and enabled) then
        repeat
            --Sleep(2)
            MoveMouseRelative(-3, 4)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(16)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-3, 4)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(17)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-3, 4)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(17)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-3, 4)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(17)
                      MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)
  
        until (IsLeftNotPressed())
    end
end
```

sec part for another weapon

```
local enabled = false

function IsLeftNotPressed()
    return not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_ACTIVATED")
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        return
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_DEACTIVATED")
        ReleaseMouseButton(1) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
        return
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
        enabled = not enabled
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and enabled) then
        repeat
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(92)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-2, 1)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(7)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-2, 1)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(6)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-2, 0)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(8)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-2, 0)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(6)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
            if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                      Sleep(8)
                      MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                      MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)
        until (IsLeftNotPressed())
    end
end
```

3rd part for the last weapon

```
local enabled = false

function IsLeftNotPressed()
    return not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_ACTIVATED")
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        return
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_DEACTIVATED")
        ReleaseMouseButton(1) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
        return
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) then
        enabled = not enabled
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and enabled) then
        repeat
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(5)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(5)
                MoveMouseRelative(-2, -1)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(85)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(5)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(5)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(5)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                Sleep(80)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
                if (IsLeftNotPressed()) then return end
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)
        until (IsLeftNotPressed())
    end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi - If function-name even nil then dofile script-file-name with function-name and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local recoil_mode  -- possible values: false, 8, 7, 6
local recoil_loops = {
   [8] = {
      {x=-3, y=4, delay=16},
      {x=-3, y=4, delay=17},
      {x=-3, y=4, delay=17},
      {x=-3, y=4, delay=17},
   },
   [7] = {
      {x=-2, y=1, delay=92},
      {x=-2, y=1, delay=7},
      {x=-2, y=0, delay=6},
      {x=-2, y=0, delay=8},
      {x=-1, y=0, delay=6},
      {x=-1, y=0, delay=8},
   },
   [6] = {
      {x=-1, y=0,  delay=5},
      {x=-2, y=-1, delay=5},
      {x=-1, y=0,  delay=85},
      {x=-1, y=0,  delay=5},
      {x=-1, y=0,  delay=5},
      {x=-1, y=0,  delay=5},
      {x=-1, y=0,  delay=80},
   },
}

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_ACTIVATED")
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      OutputLogMessage("PROFILE_DEACTIVATED")
      ReleaseMouseButton(1) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and recoil_loops[arg] then
      recoil_mode = recoil_mode ~= arg and arg
      OutputLogMessage("Recoil mode is now "..tostring(recoil_mode))
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil_mode then
      local loop = recoil_loops[recoil_mode]
      local j = 0
      repeat
         j = j % #loop + 1
         if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then  -- only when RMB pressed
            MoveMouseRelative(loop[j].x, loop[j].y)
         end
         Sleep(loop[j].delay)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```

UPDATE:
Anti-recoil works only while right mouse button is down.

Comment: my quation was : 
that when i press mouse 7 the mouse will run first script , and when i press mouse 8 will load the second ..
doesn;t matter what mouse key i just gives you an example
and thanks for your answering me

Comment: The script corresponds to your mouse buttons. To change mouse buttons (6,7,8 -> x,y,z) modify table `recoil_loops`

Comment: Bro you're amazing 
you even fixed the movment for wireless mouses big thanks , but i had to change few setting
and btw can you edit the code to make the code move only when i press right click button

Comment: To change LMB to RMB, replace `arg == 1` with `arg == 2` and `IsMouseButtonPressed(1)` with `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` and `ReleaseMouseButton(1)` with `ReleaseMouseButton(3)`.  Yes, 2 and 3, it's not a typo.

Comment: i meant when i aim and fire only will move not moving while am aiming
and i have quasstion 
can i add more key like i need to add another script but i wan't run it only if i press 'P'
is this posable ?

Comment: `i need to add another script` - post the script you want to add.  `not moving while am aiming` - what "aiming" are you talking about?  `i wan't run it only if i press 'P'` - do you want to add anti-recoil for one more weapon (1=mouse8, 2=mouse7, 3=mouse6, 4=keyP)?

Comment: Hello Egor you have been too much help for me and I appreciate that
and yes I want to add P key to the same script above with mouse6 , mouse3 .. etc
mouse4
mouse3
mouse6
"P"
and about the movement: I meant the script will run by left click only if am holding the right click

Comment: LGS doesn't send you events about pressing P key on your keyboard.  You can simulate pressing P from your script, but you can't receive event "P is pressed".

Comment: `the script will run by left click only if am holding the right click` - answer updated.

Comment: dude I hope I can help you with something .. you're amazing ... and about P key I hope I can fix this issue because I have to run like 12 scripts in 1 and the mouse didn't has so many keys that's why am asking anyway thank you again for your time

Comment: Two mouse buttons (mouse7 and mouse8) would be enough.  You can enumerate all 12 weapons in 4 bits.  To switch, press buttons 4 times: weapon#1=7777, weapon#2=7778, weapon#3=7787, and so on.  "7787" means you press a sequence: mouse7 twice, then mouse8 and again mouse7.  This would require to change the script of course.